# Configuring a Hurricane Electric IPv6 tunnel without being the default gateway

Tags: networking, centos, ipv6

I've been trying to figure out if its possible to setup a Hurricane Electric IPv6 tunnel to be configured on a CentOS VPS server, but not make it the default gateway for all IPv6 traffic, but also to be able to utilise the /64 subnet delegated via the tunnel.

Using the CentOS 7 example with a few modifications in this guide (Its a Linode VPS):

https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/set-up-an-ipv6-tunnel-on-your-linode

The reason for the tunnel to not be the default gateway is I have native IPv6 via SLAAC and a delegated /64 already, but was hoping to add the IPv6 tunnel as a bit of a failover scenario/additional IPv6 network route to services running on this server.

All configurations I have seen in regards to setting up a "he-ipv6" interface, basically take over the default gateway, which makes my native IPv6 address space no longer pingable to the WAN side, but connectivity like ping and traceroute still works within the server on both interfaces, tested by specifying the specific interface on tests.

#### traceroute -6 -i eth0 ipv6.google.com

```
traceroute to ipv6.google.com (2a00:1450:400b:801::200e), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  2a01:7e00::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx (2a01:7e00::8678:acff:fe5a:1a41)  0.919 ms  1.358 ms  1.425 ms
 2  2a01:7e00:7777:6::1 (2a01:7e00:7777:6::1)  0.832 ms 2a01:7e00:7777:1::1 (2a01:7e00:7777:1::1)  0.893 ms 2a01:7e00:7777:3::1 (2a01:7e00:7777:3::1)  2.858 ms
 3  2001:7f8:4::3b41:1 (2001:7f8:4::3b41:1)  1.489 ms  1.489 ms  1.470 ms
 4  2001:4860:0:1102::2 (2001:4860:0:1102::2)  1.768 ms 2001:4860:0:1103::3 (2001:4860:0:1103::3)  2.129 ms  2.306 ms
 5  2607:f8b0:e000:8000::6 (2607:f8b0:e000:8000::6)  11.461 ms 2001:4860::c:4000:dd7a (2001:4860::c:4000:dd7a)  30.924 ms  30.940 ms
 6  2001:4860::1:0:b04f (2001:4860::1:0:b04f)  12.182 ms  14.449 ms  13.446 ms
 7  2001:4860:0:1::1223 (2001:4860:0:1::1223)  10.631 ms  10.818 ms  11.042 ms
 8  dub08s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400b:801::200e)  11.695 ms  12.338 ms  11.674 ms
```

#### traceroute -6 -i he-ipv6 ipv6.google.com

```
traceroute to ipv6.google.com (2a00:1450:400b:c00::8b), 30 hops max, 80 byte pac                 kets
 1  jamesnetworks-3.tunnel.tserv1.lon2.ipv6.he.net (2001:470:1f1c:xxx::1)  5.321                  ms  8.443 ms  11.440 ms
 2  ge3-20.core1.lon2.he.net (2001:470:0:320::1)  11.657 ms  11.635 ms  11.610 m                 s
 3  2001:7f8:4::3b41:1 (2001:7f8:4::3b41:1)  12.799 ms  12.776 ms  12.745 ms
 4  2001:4860:0:1::2484 (2001:4860:0:1::2484)  12.380 ms 2001:4860:0:1103::3 (20                 01:4860:0:1103::3)  13.500 ms 2001:4860:0:1103::2 (2001:4860:0:1103::2)  12.769                  ms
 5  2001:4860::c:4000:dd7a (2001:4860::c:4000:dd7a)  12.871 ms 2607:f8b0:e000:80                 00::6 (2607:f8b0:e000:8000::6)  22.566 ms 2001:4860::c:4000:dd7a (2001:4860::c:4                 000:dd7a)  13.663 ms
 6  2001:4860::1:0:af90 (2001:4860::1:0:af90)  20.897 ms  11.010 ms  12.375 ms
 7  2001:4860::2:0:b051 (2001:4860::2:0:b051)  12.114 ms  22.411 ms  11.200 ms
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  dg-in-x8b.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400b:c00::8b)  11.499 ms  11.035 ms  11.800 ms
```

I've set up the tunnel and confirm it works, but my two /64 IPv6 address spaces don't work when both enabled. I'm looking for further guidance on what routing config I need to have to get this to work, possibly slightly outside the scope covered in the docs above.

The default gateway on the `eth0` device it setup as:

```
default via fe80::1 dev eth0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1796sec
```

When enabling the `he-ipv6` interface, this is added in addition to the above:

```
default via 2001:470:1fxx:xx::1 dev he-ipv6 metric 1
```

The metric being higher, all traffic then tries to go through the `he-ipv6` interface, which is not what I want. Equally, having two "default" routes seems like a bad idea.

What I'm trying to do is keep the native IPv6 connectivity working, while having the he-ipv6 active and available for traffic to be routed to the configured IPv6 addresses in my routed /64 via the tunnel, in addition to the existing /64 from Linode.

I believe I'll need to potentially do some static routing here, but unsure of how to tackle it.

So far, with being able to control the metric properly as per the guidance below, this is what the IPv6 routing table looks like:

```
unreachable ::/96 dev lo metric 1024 error -113
unreachable ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96 dev lo metric 1024 error -113
# Additional route added by he-ipv6
2001:470:1f1c:xxx::/64 dev he-ipv6 proto kernel metric 256
# Adding any IPv6 in the HE routed /64 to eth0 adds the route below
2001:470:1f1d:xxx::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256
unreachable 2002:a00::/24 dev lo metric 1024 error -113
unreachable 2002:7f00::/24 dev lo metric 1024 error -113
unreachable 2002:a9fe::/32 dev lo metric 1024 error -113
unreachable 2002:ac10::/28 dev lo metric 1024 error -113
unreachable 2002:c0a8::/32 dev lo metric 1024 error -113
unreachable 2002:e000::/19 dev lo metric 1024 error -113
# Linode SLAAC IPv6
2a01:7e00::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 expires 14395sec
2a01:7e00:xxxx:xxx::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256
unreachable 3ffe:ffff::/32 dev lo metric 1024 error -113
# Having fe80::/64 for both interfaces seems wrong?
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256
fe80::/64 dev he-ipv6 proto kernel metric 256
# eth0 (Linode IPv4/IPv6)
default via fe80::1 dev eth0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1795sec hoplimit 64
# he-ipv6
default via 2001:470:1f1c:xxx::1 dev he-ipv6 metric 1025
```

The two references for `fe80::/64` don't seem right here, I don't think the he-ipv6 would need this set in this case and I possibly need additional static routes to allow the routed /64 addresses to be externally accessible.

Any advice or solutions would be appreciated on getting this working!

Comment: Just change the metrics.

Comment: @RonMaupin These are automatically added when the interfaces come up.  How can I override them? Also have two "default" routes, is probably not a good ides is it?

Comment: "_# Having fe80::/64 for both interfaces seems wrong?_" That would be the correct link-local network; the `fe80::/10` network is the link-local network for all interfaces in IPv6. You should not have a route for the link-local network. Yo use link-local addressing, you must use it with a scope identifier, e.g. `fe80::1%eth0`.

Comment: @RonMaupin That's what's been added automatically by Linode's IPv6 configuration via SLAAC by the looks of it. If I add `IPV6_DEFAULTGW` with `fe80::1%eth0` on eth0, that then adds the default with a metric of 1, which is fine, but then I still can't get any ping response externally from any HE address in my router /64. The issue is having the connectivity from both /64 subnets at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

It's fine to have two default routes but, as Ron points out in the comments, you'll almost certainly want them to have different metrics such that normally one (presumably the ethernet interface) will normally be preferred.

You'll want to edit the `ifup` script you added for the `he-ipv6` interface and add `METRIC=100` to the bottom.  When the tunnel interface is brought up this should result in two default routes, the existing one with a metric of 1 and the new one with a metric of 100.  If the default route via the ethernet port goes away then v6 traffic will start to flow via the tunnel.

Keep in mind that you may also want to add some additional v6 static routes via the tunnel interface based on what you'd like to reach via HE.

**EDIT:** Redhat/CentOS doesn't consistently implement/honor the METRIC value across the various interface scripts.  You could certainly modify these scripts to include this value but this might not be desirable from an operability point of view, as you'd need to track any changes made upstream to these stock scripts.

So... you can do this from the CLI pretty easily:

`sudo ip -6 delete default via 2001:470:1fxx:xx::1 dev he-ipv6
sudo ip -6 add default via 2001:470:1fxx:xx::1 dev he-ipv6 metric 100`

You could also add this to be run automatically by creating a script called `/sbin/ifup-local` that would look something like this:

`#!/bin/sh
if [[ "$1" == "he-ipv6" ]]
then
  sudo ip -6 delete default via 2001:470:1fxx:xx::1 dev he-ipv6
  sudo ip -6 add default via 2001:470:1fxx:xx::1 dev he-ipv6 metric 100
else
  #DO_NOTHING
fi`

This should be called automatically by CentOS after each interface is brought up but will only do anything if the interface in question is literally "he-ipv6".

Comment: Thanks your answer. OK I wasn't sure if having multiple defaults was bad or not. I understand the use of metric order, but for whatever reason, applying any `METRIC=x` value doesn't get reflected, based on the output of `ip -6 route`. The `he-ipv6` interface is always to set 1, while eth0 is `1024`. Not sure where that value is coming from, its configured via SLAAC though.

Comment: Hmm... I looked closely at a Centos 7 box and it's definitely the case that the logic doesn't actually allow the metric to be set.  This means that you'd have to either alter the default scripts to have it pull out the metric value and add it to the ipv6_set_default_route function in the network-functions-ipv6 file (...and then add it to the appropriate ifup-xxx script) or you could build your own script to call to remove and re-add the route with the right metric.  I'll edit the answer with the basic CLI.

Comment: Thanks. That works and give me control of setting the metric value. I'll note the ifup-local script for future reference. In order to have IPv6 addresses from the routed /64 from HE, will I need to add another static route? The routing table still looks a bit strange. I've updated the original post.